# Change audit directory permission to another user beside root

Tags: permissions, rhel, audit

I want to grant permision to another user for audit directory.

```
[user_audit@crox log]$ cd audit
bash: cd: audit: Permission denied
[user_audit@crox log]$ ls -lrt | grep audit
drwx------. 2 root         user_audit    1006 Jul  3 13:37 audit
[user_audit@crox log]$cat /etc/os-release
NAME= Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.8
```

Are there any extra steps involved beside a chown ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the permissions you can use

chmod 755 to give rwx to owner rx to group and rx to public

if you want to change owner you can you chown see man chown.

see https://chmod-calculator.com/ if you need help to understand peemissions